# VueJS warning when using dynamic components and custom-events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

So, I get this warning:

> " Extraneous non-emits event listeners (addNewResource) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option."

And I don't understand why. I am using dynamic components with 2 custom events. I've tried adding both of the emitted events to the `emits` object of both components.

**`App.vue`**

```
<template>
  <AppHeader />
  <NavigationBar @select-component="selectComponent" />
  <keep-alive>
    <component
      :is="selectedComponent"
      v-bind="componentProps"
      @delete-resource="deleteResource"
      @add-new-resource="addNewResource"
    ></component>
  </keep-alive>
</template>

<script>
import AppHeader from "./components/SingleFile/AppHeader.vue";
import NavigationBar from "./components/NavigationBar.vue";
import LearningResources from "./components/LearningResources.vue";
import AddResource from "./components/AddResource.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    AppHeader,
    NavigationBar,
    LearningResources,
    AddResource,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedComponent: "learning-resources",
      learningResources: [
        {
          name: "Official Guide",
          description: "The official Vue.js documentation",
          link: "https://v3.vuejs.org",
        },
        {
          name: "Google",
          description: "Learn to google...",
          link: "https://www.google.com/",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectComponent(component) {
      this.selectedComponent = component;
    },
    deleteResource(name) {
      this.learningResources = this.learningResources.filter(
        (resource) => resource.name !== name
      );
    },
    addNewResource(newResourceObject) {
      const newResource = {
        name: newResourceObject.title,
        description: newResourceObject.description,
        link: newResourceObject.link,
      };
      this.learningResources.push(newResource);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    componentProps() {
      if (this.selectedComponent === "learning-resources") {
        return {
          learningResources: this.learningResources,
        };
      }
      return null;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**`AddResource.vue`**

```
<template>
  <base-card>
    <template #default>
      <form @submit.prevent>
        <div>
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" v-model="newResource.title" />
        </div>
        <br />

        <div>
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea rows="3" v-model="newResource.description" />
        </div>
        <br />

        <div>
          <label for="link">Link</label>
          <input type="text" v-model="newResource.link" />
        </div>

        <button @click="$emit('add-new-resource', newResource)">
          Add Resource
        </button>
      </form>
    </template>
  </base-card>
</template>

<script>
import BaseCard from "./Base/BaseCard.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    BaseCard,
  },
  emits: ["add-new-resource"],
  data() {
    return {
      newResource: {
        title: "",
        description: "",
        link: "",
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**`LearningResources.vue`**

```
<template>
  <base-card v-for="resource in learningResources" :key="resource.name">
    <template #header>
      <h3>{{ resource.name }}</h3>
      <button @click="$emit('delete-resource', resource.name)">Delete</button>
    </template>

    <template #default>
      <p>{{ resource.description }}</p>
      <p><a :href="resource.link">View Resource</a></p>
    </template>
  </base-card>
</template>

<script>
import BaseCard from "./Base/BaseCard.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    BaseCard,
  },
  props: {
    learningResources: Array,
  },
  emits: ["deleteResource"],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be because `<component>` is being used for two separate components, neither of which emit the same event as the other.

One thing you can try is [disabling each components' attribute inheritance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance):

```js
export default {
    ...
    inheritAttrs: false
    ...
}
```

If this doesn't suit your needs, you could refactor the logic to handle both emitted events, i.e. rename the events to a shared name like `"addOrDeleteResource"`, then determine which event is being emitted in `App.vue` and handle it accordingly.

Comment: The passed props and emits events are not passed to $attrs, so I can't use the first suggestion

Comment: What about the first suggestion doesn't work? I tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: Ill try again, maybe I didn't use it right =)

Comment: If you add the snippet from my answer: `inheritAttrs: false` anywhere in `export default {...}` it should work

Comment: Now it works. Thanks. But now I have another question, how and why does that work? =))

Comment: As the error says: the event `...could not be automatically inherited`. So, by disabling attribute inheritance, you prevent the compiler from running through this step and trying to set a custom event which isn't needed by the component. I'm not sure how this might affect your other attributes, though, so keep an eye out and if you run into any errors with it, try using `$attrs` like the docs say

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I got it. So, the custom events that are in the "emits" object will not be pushed inside $attrs, only the props and custom events not specified in the component. So, if I disable inheritAttrs, it doesn't pass the second event. Thank you for helping me here =)