# Vue.js "Extraneous non-emits event listeners" warning for events on RouterView

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to emit events from my child components up to my `App.vue` top-level component, but I use a `RouterView` to actually render my child components in my `App.vue` template:

```
<template>
    <Navbar />
    <component :is="$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
        <RouterView @display-modal="handleDisplayModal" />
    </component>
</template>
```

This causes Vue to give me the console warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Extraneous non-emits event listeners (displayModal) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option. 
  at <Home onDisplayModal=fn<handleDisplaymodal> onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView onDisplayModal=fn<handleDisplaymodal> > 
  at <LayoutBoxed> 
  at <App>
```

I can't declare this event with "emits" because RouterView isn't my component.  How can I get rid of this warning?  I'd like a solution where I don't have to modify all the views that get rendered by router-view (and, indeed, any future such views I might add).

My versions of:

vue: 3.2.47
vue-router: 4.1.6

Comment: What is vue and vue-router versions?

Comment: I've added them to the question.

Comment: we are using pinia as a state manager and created store where rather than emitting events through the chain of components upto the top level component, we just added the event state to the pinia and just used the pinia subscribe method in the  mounted method the state checked with the if condition so code just executed for particular state change and adjusted the display modal value. This reduced the too many emits from the app and also parent to child or child to parent chain.

Comment: Also create a component which renders your dynamic component and pass the route props to that component and handle the displayModal property there

Comment: @wui State changes are not events. A state watcher watching a state that is updated twice in quick succession will happily ignore the intermediate state and only fire for the final state, which is no good if you need it to fire for every state change. Add for the component suggestion, please pay that as an answer with a code example. If it works I can award the bounty.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue. I created a repo to show what I have tried. Feel free to push any changes to modify it. https://github.com/abdul-alhasany/vue-router-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `inheritAttrs: false` making Home ignore passed attributes seems to fix the problem

```js
<template>
  <h2>Hello world</h2>
  <RouterLink to="/Another">Link to Another</RouterLink>
</template>
<script>
// use normal <script> to declare options
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>
```

See [VueJS warning when using dynamic components and custom-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554948/vuejs-warning-when-using-dynamic-components-and-custom-events)

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution because it does correctly identify the problem and *a* fix, but IMHO there's no particularly good workaround and it's basically a bug Vue needs to fix: you should be able to say at the attribute level, "this attribute should not be a fallthrough attribute". That way when you have a dynamic component like `router-view`, the views that implement the event can emit it and the ones that don't won't be affected and won't cause the "Extraneous nonemits event listeners" warning. My feature request for this is [submitted here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/8024)

Comment: This solution requires always making every child component of a `router-view` either explicitly emit all listened-for events, or not inherit attributes, neither of which is desirable or particuarly maintainable.  The problem is the fallthrough behaviour which can't be disabled for these event listener attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is designed to inform developers that components with multiple root nodes do not have an automatic [attribute fallthrough](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes) behavior. So if you are already aware of it, you can completely ignore it. Your component still works as expected regardless of the existence of that warning.

If you still want to get rid of that warning, you have 2 options:

**Option 1:** Add `inheritAttrs:false` to the component that introduces the warning. It will tell Vue that you do not want to use attribute fallthrough in that component. It seems a little verbose and non-sense but that is the trade-off of using frameworks/libraries. Some features are not necessary for you but will be very helpful for other developers

**Option 2:** Write a warning handler to manually filter the warning

```js
  app.config.warnHandler = function (msg, vm, trace) {
    if (msg.includes('Extraneous non-emits event listeners (displayModal)')) {
      return
    }
    console.warn(msg, trace)
  }
```

Comment: It sucks that there isn't a way to suppress this just for a router view, because this is kind of specific to the use case of listening for an event on a router view and only caring if certain rendered children emit that event.

Comment: @Jez I also faced it in my project and just ignored it. Technically, `vue-router` is just a plugin in the Vue perspective so there is no special treat

Comment: I'm not in the habit of ignoring console warnings.  When I'm trying to debug, a bunch of spurious warnings are extremely annoying.  And the vue-router people on Github don't seem to care either, closing down issues about it.  Honestly, their attitude alone is reason enough to use React over Vue.  It's absolutely infuriating.  Unless you're Evan You, you can't get any change in Vue.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's spurious, it is important to at least be aware that you're setting attributes that _can't_ fallthrough to certain child components.  This is why Vue 2 required a single root element in every component, so you never had the option of running into this issue.  You could always revert back to designing your components according to that paradigm.  Wrapping your template code in a single div won't affect emits and seems like the smallest tax to pay if the other methods of handling the warning aren't good enough.

Comment: @Jez I came across your discussion on the vue-router repository. Just wanted to share my opinion that I think the maintainer is correct in this situation - it doesn't seem related to vue-router. And I don't see a way for vue-router to fix this problem from the plugin side. As you can see from the suggestions provided by myself and yoduh, there are various options available to solve the issue. It just means that you'll have to take care of it yourself, rather than relying on the maintainer to fix it.

Comment: Couldn't the router declare that attributes aren't inherited, and manually process them to avoid the warning, silently dropping ones that can't be inherited?

Comment: I added an [improvement request](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/8024) that would probably be the way to deal with it at the core Vue level, but watch it get shut down as "not planned" or something.

Comment: @Jez vue-router does [turn off attributes inherited](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/src/RouterView.ts#L47) and manually pass them to each component. But it doesn't matter. vue-router needs to pass the props down to the child component regardless to support all scenarios

Answer (score -1):

There is no version information available for `router-view` so I'm assuming you are using `vue-router@4`:

since the render component of `router-view` is assumed to be nothing so it represents the parent element of the routes so use component:

```js
<router-view v-slot='{ Component }'>
    <component :is='Component' @display-modal='handle' />
</router-view>
```

also i encourage people to use event bus instead of complicated logic

Comment: That still gives me the same warning.

Comment: please add the code of the route I suspect you haven't declared the event

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  Where am I supposed to declare the event?  Could you update your answer to provide a code example?

Comment: provide an example of a component that calls emit event i will show it to you

Comment: I filed [a bug](https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/1735) about it on Github and it seems that the event has to be declared on the Home component in order to not get the warning.  I consider this a bug in Vue Router, personally.

Comment: as i said above this is an important feature that was updated in vue 3 not a bug

Comment: What do you mean?  It seems that the first component configured in the router has to define the event to be emitted, even if you want to listen to the event on the `router-view` from a different component.  So if you have `Home.vue` and then later on you have `Game.vue` in your `router.js`, and you want to emit the event from `Game.vue`, you have to `defineEmits(['myevent'])` on both `Game.vue` and `Home.vue` to stop this warning.  How is that useful?  I don't need to emit it from `Home.vue`.